# VBScript: Get system tray application list

Tags: vbscript

How to get the list of application in system tray using vbscript? I have searched but could not find anything for it in vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a program, but not VBS, can find out about the status area.

dwMessage
[in] Variable of type DWORD that specifies the action to be taken. It can have one of the following values.

**NIM_ADD**
Adds an icon to the status area. The hWnd and uID members of the NOTIFYICONDATA structure pointed to by lpdata will be used to identify the icon in later calls to Shell_NotifyIcon.

**NIM_DELETE**
Deletes an icon from the status area. Use the hWnd and uID members of the NOTIFYICONDATA structure pointed to by lpdata to identify the icon to be deleted.

**NIM_MODIFY**
Modifies an icon in the status area. Use the hWnd and uID members of the NOTIFYICONDATA structure pointed to by lpdata to identify the icon to be modified.

**NIM_SETFOCUS**
Version 5.0. Returns focus to the taskbar notification area. Taskbar icons should use this message when they have completed their user interface operation. For example, if the taskbar icon displays a shortcut menu, but the user presses ESC to cancel it, use NIM_SETFOCUS to return focus to the taskbar notification area.

**NIM_SETVERSION**
Version 5.0. Instructs the taskbar to behave according to the version number specified in the uVersion member of the structure pointed to by lpdata. This message allows you to specify whether you want the version 5.0 behavior found on Microsoft Windows 2000 systems, or that found with earlier Shell versions. The default value for uVersion is zero, indicating that the original Windows 95 notify icon behavior should be used. For details, see the Remarks section.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible to do this in VBScript?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm also saying their is no inbuilt mechanism for any language as no program needs to know this stuff. If important to you try looking for Windows. Each icon is a Window. Again VBScript has no window functions.

Comment: BTW, I keep saying VBScript can't this/that. Windows also has VB.NET, that can, with difficulty, do almost anything. There is no documentation on using notepad to write vb.net programs (except, to a limited extent, another person and myself). But VBScript is compatible with VB.NET (except subs in VB.NET require brackets like functions do in all other basics).